# Why this regex expression matching lines with (not N) number of comma doesn't work with vim?

Tags: regular-expression

I'm trying to fix a csv file but the regex expression won't work.

I want to jump to lines that have a number of commas that is different than 5. I first select lines with less than 5 so I press `/` and type

```
^[^,\r\n]*(?:,[^,\r\n]*){0,4}$`
```

but it won't match anything. It's not the first time that I can't match a regex that is otherwise working on other engines, what is happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vim regex engine doesn't work exactly like other engines. It includes different 'magic modes' which change the characters that you have to escape.

See [`:h /magic`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fmagic) for a list of the characters to escape and more generally [`:h pattern.txt`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern.txt) to learn how to use regexes on Vim.

To make your search work you should use:

```
^[^,\r\n]*\(,[^,\r\n]*\)\{0,4}$
```

Comment: What about lines that have more or less than 19 semi colons ? I tried this: `/^[^;\r\n]*\(;[^;\r\n]*\)\{0,19}$`

Comment: @Stephane you're matching between 0 and 19 semi colons with your regex. To do what you want I think you'll have to create a more complex regex which will match lines with less than 19 semi colons *and* lines with more than 19 semi colons. Depending on what you actually want to do, you could also use a regex which matches exactly 19 semicolons (`{19}`) and the `:v` command which applies a command on the lines which are not matched by the regex. See [`:h :v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%3av) and maybe ask a new question if you need more help :-)